# How do I create a self-updating line graph when new information is input every week in Excel table without including the total?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, charts

I have a line graph with the performance of two employees. 
How do I get Excel to automatically show only the last five weeks’ numbers without me having to select the data manually and without the "total" column showing up on my graph. 
Here’s a screenshot of my data:

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: any info on how the "last 5 weeks numbers" data "mapped" to the " line graph " ? || btw the "totals" came from (which data/column/week) ? || share some screenshot or sample data.. That'll clarify the case.. ( :

Comment: Finite range or infinite range?

Comment: Joe: Your question is very confusing.   (1) Why didn’t you ***say*** that you had uploaded a screenshot of your data?   (2) You say “new information is input every week”, but your screenshot shows monthly data.   (3) What’s the deal with the totals?  Your screenshot shows a total column between “Month6” and “Month7” — but it’s called “Q1 Total”, and “Q” typically stands for “quarter”, and, of course, a quarter is three months.  So, do you have a “total” column every six columns, or what?

Answer (score 0):

Create a dummy region
that automatically shows the last five weeks’ performance (and only that). 
Let’s suppose your raw data are in Columns `A` and `B`. 
Pick a 2×6 range that you aren’t using.* 
It could be on another sheet, or it could be way out, e.g., `AA1:AB6`. 
I’ll assume that you’ve chosen `G1:H6`. 
Copy your column headers to `G1` and `H1`. 
Enter

```
=INDEX(A:A, COUNTA(A:A)+ROW()-6)
```

into `G2`. 
Drag/fill down to `G6` (i.e., for five weeks)
and right to `H2:H6` (for two employees). 
`G2:H6` will now display the last five weeks’ data from `A:B`.

Quick explanation:

- `COUNTA(A:A)` counts the number of non-blank cells in Column `A`. 
  If the most recent cell, and all the cells above it, are non-blank,
  and all the cells below it are blank,
  then this will give you the row number of the most recent data. 
  If you have blank cells above, or non-blank cells below,
  you will need adjust this or devise something different.
- `ROW()` is the number of the row that it is in. 
  I.e., in `G2` and `H2`, it is 2; in `G6` and `H6`, it is 6.
- `COUNTA(A:A)+ROW()-6` is `(COUNTA(A:A)-5+1) + (ROW()-2)`.

  - `(COUNTA(A:A)-5+1)` is the row number of the fifth-to-last week’s data. 
    For example, if you have 100 rows of data,
    then the last five are 96, 97, 98, 99 and 100, and 100−5+1 is 96.
  - `(ROW()-2)` is the zero-based row number within the `G2:H6` range. 
    I.e., in `G2` and `H2`, it is 0; in `G6` and `H6`, it is 4.
  - So, adding them, we get the numbers of the fifth-to-last row,
    the fourth-to-last row, the third-to-last row, the second-to-last row,
    and the last row (e.g., 96, 97, 98, 99 and 100).
- `INDEX(A:A, <row_number>)` gets the value
  from the indicated row in Column `A`. 
  When you drag the formula from Column `G` to Column `H`,
  this automatically changes
  to `INDEX(B:B, <row_number>)`.

So `G1:H6` shows the last five weeks’ performance (including column headers). 
Base your chart on that range:

[image: Rows 3-7]

If you add data to Columns `A` and `B`, the chart will automatically adapt:

[image: Rows 4-8]

______________
* You could probably use a 2×5 range by not including the column headers.